# Rally Put request throwing Not authorized , Invalid key error . sporadically

Tags: java, spring-boot, rally, code-rally, rallyapi

I am trying to use an api of Rally Ticketing system . to fetch the security token using username and password , later i am making another request . using Put Method , and passsing that security token in params to perform update operation.
I want to know that the cookies i received in response , that i got when i fetched token, will be automatically set in headers when i make put request to that same domain ? also i think it is setting internally , because when i set it manually in code , before put request , i am getting this error
" Duplicate valid session cookies: gi-app-141ghvfdmt0m0dhr0346o4c9cwm73282.gi-app-14 ,gi-app-141t77o0a6e7nxf68rak1etqxdg73288.gi-app-14 "

I want to know what to do because when i do not set cookie, i get
"Not Authorized , Invalid Key error"

Any help would be appreciated.